# Easiest way to "fill" payload?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, scapy

I wan't to send a UDP packet with a arbitrary packet size depending on my input argument, so whenever my "data" is not enough to fill up the wanted packet payload I want to just "fill" the rest with empty data.

So if I send `123` but I want the packet to be of size 100 bytes, the method will pad the packet with the access data, I don't want to iterate and add spaces to fill it out manually.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
>>> from scapy.all import *
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
>>> p = IP(dst="62.21.20.21")/UDP()
>>> p = p/Raw('a'*(100-len(p)))
>>> send(p)
.
Sent 1 packets.
>>>

# tcpdump -ni cplane0 udp -e -v -X
tcpdump: listening on cplane0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
10:15:31.904204 54:ab:3a:56:59:1e > fa:16:3e:e1:9e:14, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 114: (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 1, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 100)
    44.60.11.3.53 > 62.21.20.21.53: 24929 updateM+ [b2&3=0x6161] [24929a] [24929q] [24929n] [24929au][|domain]
        0x0000:  4500 0064 0001 0000 3e11 f31f 2c3c 0b03  E..d....>...,<..
        0x0010:  3e15 1415 0035 0035 0050 c3c9 6161 6161  >....5.5.P..aaaa
        0x0020:  6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        0x0030:  6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        0x0040:  6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        0x0050:  6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        0x0060:  6161 6161                                aaaa
```

Please note "proto UDP (17), length 100" in tcpdump output.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a padding `bytearray()`, and just prepend (or append) it to your payload:

```
payload = b'123'
padding_length = 100 - len(payload)
padding_byte = b' '
return bytearray(padding_byte * padding_length) + payload
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a networking expert, but you might want to take a look at [struct.pack()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html)

This will zero pad a length of characters and should be blazing fast:

```
from struct import pack

result = pack('!100s', 'input_value')
```

This also allows you to mind the endian-ness of your data if that is important in your domain. In this case the data appears right null padded.

Hope that helps!